# Flowtype: How to create type guard function?

Tags: flowtype

I want to use [type refinements](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/) from function.
How to create [type guard](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html) function (TypeScript) in flow?

**I** TypeScript example:

```
function isString(arg: Showable): arg is string {
    return typeof arg === 'string';
}
```

**II** Flow

```
/* @flow */
type Showable = number | string;

// ok
function barOk (arg: Showable) {
  return typeof arg === 'string' ? arg.length : (arg + 1);
}

// type guard function
function isString(arg: Showable) {
    return typeof arg === 'string';
}

// Error
function barError (arg: Showable) {
  return isString(arg) ? arg.length : (arg + 1);
                         // ^ Cannot get `arg.length` because property `length` is missing in `Number`
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `isString` function to the following:

```
function isString(arg: Showable): boolean %checks {
    return typeof arg === 'string';
}
```

See [Predicate Functions](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-predicate-functions)

Comment: typescript version: `function isString(arg: Showable): arg is boolean {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Flow implemented [Type Guards](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/type-guards/) and are deprecating the `%checks` since [v0.224.0](https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases/tag/v0.224.0)

They recommend the type guard syntax instead (similar to TS):

```js
 function isString(arg: any): arg is string {
     return typeof arg === "string";
 }
```